# Grails redirect, forward and render alter view and shows Grails banner/template

Tags: grails, grails-controller

When I redirect to another page, Grails alters the screen by adding a banner that looks like this:

[image]

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
def login() {
    def user = userService.login(params.username, params.password)
    if(user){
        chain (action: "main", model: [user:user])
    }else{
        redirect (uri: "/")
    }
}

def main() {

}
```

I tried using forward and render instead of redirect, but the banner is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand you, but maybe you are rendering a gsp which has the meta layout included in the head block.

```
<meta name="layout" content="main">
```

Just delete it. If I am right you can find more info here:
[grails layouts](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#layouts)